# How to add css for div tag and Panel in asp

Tags: asp.net, css

How do I add css for the Panle and the div tag, I am new to this I tried many ways but could not make it to work. How should I add css for individual Panel and individual Div tag. Thanks

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
    <link href="Styles/AboutUs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" >
         <div id="main">
         </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>


CSS:
----
.Panel2
{
position: relative;
 top: -11px;
 left: -20px; 
 height: 450px;
 width: 928px;
}


.main
{
position: relative;
top: 17px;
left: 154px;
height: 110px;
width: 691px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this HTML

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" >
         <div id="main">
         </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Change it to (see the change in BOLD)

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" **CssClass="pnlCSS"**>
         <div id="main">
         </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

and the css should be

```
#main
{
position: relative;
top: 17px;
left: 154px;
height: 110px;
width: 691px;
}
.pnlCSS
{
// CSS for panel here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you what to use Ids instead of `CssClass` you will have to change your `ClientIDMode="Static"`:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" >
     <div id="main">
     </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is look at the div and panel class in Firebug - when using ASP.NET Master pages, it will append certain things to your specified class; it will look something like #ct100_MainContent etc etc.

Again, take a look at Firebug and see what the div is being written to the browser as, and update that in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CssClass` property to define a css class for you panel div.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="myClass">
</asp:Panel>
```

And then use this class in your css:

```
.myClass {
 position: relative;
 top: -11px;
 left: -20px; 
 height: 450px;
 width: 928px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

#main

{
position: relative;
top: 17px;
left: 154px;
height: 110px;
width: 691px;
}

and add CssClass="Panel2" to the panel